# Is Rasa-core train on actual dialog data behind the scene?

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core

Since the core trains on domain.yml and stories.yml, without depending on the users' words (nlu.yml), I understand that RASA-Core training has nothing to do with the NLU part. It solely trains on the 'intent-action' pair, not the actual dialog data:

```
* greet
    - utter_greet
```

Is this correct? In such a case, I think the training data for dialog policy training is always going to be small, because it trains on the abstract intent-action pairs, not the actual data. In another words, dialog policy training is totally independent from NLU.

Is this understanding correct? Just want to confirm this understanding.

Comment: Yes `rasa_core` training is not related to nlu training. They are trained separately.
`rasa_core` only uses result from `rasa_nlu`. `rasa_core` provides a threshold setting to filter out low confidence results from NLU.

Comment: @mvs, can I say that the training data for RASA-core typically won't exceed a few thousands? since there is no automatic way to create it. Even manual creation of the intent-action pair is much more difficult than other ML annotation task. Is that the case?

Comment: `rasa_core` needs much less training. you need to specify all possible intent-action sequences in stories.
A thousand training also seems too much for a chatbot with not many intents.

Comment: @mvs, That's good to know. Do you have any recommendation on how to create "all possible" intent-action sequences in stories? For example, if I already have a lot of real life historical customer service dialog log (created through online chats by customers and customer service people), how to create those intent-action pairs?

Answer (score 0):

> In another words, dialog policy training is totally independent from NLU.

This is right for the training. However, in production Rasa Core uses the extracted entities from Rasa NLU and of course the classified intents.

> abstract intent-action pairs

It should only be "pairs" if you are doing a FAQ chatbot. If you actually want to handle more complex conversation, then you have to write more stories. As you can see in [this Rasa demo](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa-demo/tree/master/data/core) the required training data can get quite large for more complex chatbots.

> how to create those intent-action pairs?

You actually have to design your training stories manually. There is currently no way to so automatically. See [this blog post](https://blog.rasa.com/designing-rasa-training-stories/) which gives some recommendations how to write better training stories for Rasa Core.